# Need to do TOTAL across a intersection in mysql

Tags: mysql, metabase

I am using a opensource tool which do simple analytics. I have a mysql table for my analytics application.

I have a table say TBC which has has fields:

**TBC table:**

```
date                  amount           product
2020-05-18 17:23:44   400               A
2020-05-19 17:23:44   500               B
2020-06-08 17:23:44   100               A
2020-06-25 17:23:44   700               C
2020-06-18 17:23:44   200               B
2020-07-09 17:23:44   800               C
2020-07-19 17:23:44   900               A
```

I've written this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M,%Y') AS `date`,
   `TBC`.`product` AS `revenue`,
   count(*) AS `count`
FROM `TBC`
GROUP BY str_to_date(concat(date_format(`TBC`.`date`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'),
         `TBC`.`revenue`
ORDER BY str_to_date(concat(date_format(`TBC`.`date`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') DESC, `tbc`.`revenue` ASC
```

This gives me:

```
revenue       July,2020  June,2020  May,2020
A              900        100        400
B               --        200        500
C              800        700         --
```

I now want to have this below one:

```
revenue       July,2020  June,2020  May,2020
A              900        100        400
B               --        200        500
C              800        700         --
TOTAL          1700       1000       900
```

I know I need to use the SUM function but not sure which field I have to use .

Comment: Isn't it `SUM(amount)` ?

Comment: I tried WITH ROLLUP 

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M,%Y') AS date, TBC.product AS revenue, count(*) AS count FROM TBC GROUP BY str_to_date(concat(date_format(TBC.date, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), TBC.revenue WITH ROLLUP ORDER BY str_to_date(concat(date_format(TBC.date, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') DESC, tbc.revenue ASC 

It errors out Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: What is your mysql version ? It works fine on 8.0.20

Comment: mysql version is 8.0.21

Comment: any help from anyone?